# pytest print statements only work when issued before quit()

Tags: python, pytest

I have a pytest class that looks as following:

```
class TestModule:

    def test_print(self):
        print("test")
```

This test only passes without printing anything.

```
    def test_print(self):
        print("test")
        quit()
```

This prints test and then raises. Is there a reason for that? How can you print to stdout in pytest?

Answer (score 0):

Print statements show if you add an -s flag when running it